# При перезагрузки страницы появляется страница 404

Tags: reactjs

Когда перезагружаю страницу на сайте в консоли появляется ошибка: GET http://xn----htbnogdjhj.xn--p1acf/category 404 (Not Found). Хотя локально работает все корректно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используете React-Router-DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Создавайте файл с имени .htaccess добывайте это внутри файла

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

таким образом должно работать

Comment: Дело в том, что этот файл уже создан в папке public и содержимое уже добавлено и откомпилировано через npm run build, соответственно этот файл теперь и в папке build

Comment: @b.ars, а вы уверены, что он помещается в папку build? Вроде бы `npm run build` просто собирает все файлы в бандл и все, посторонние файлы без настройки он никуда не перемещает

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с данной проблемой, дописав скрипт в файле deploy.sh

```
echo "Swithing to branch main"
git checkout main

echo "building app..."
npm run build

echo "Deploying files to server..."
scp -r build/* путь

echo "Done!"
```

Тем самым адекватно заработал nginx